# writing to a text file - batch

Tags: batch-file

soo I am making inventory, here is datastructrue
`{"sword":"old sword",}`

here is how am i reading from it

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (eq.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%c in ("%%b") do (
      echo %%c|findstr "!string!">nul && set test=%%~d
    )
  )
)
```

but, well i really dont know how to CHANGE or WRITE values in this. for example, at first i have
`{"sword":"",}`
and i want to input something in the brackets to get
`{"sword":"old sword",}`
i hope i ve explained it good.

Comment: Is there a point to formatting it in that filetype in that manner? Is the Inventory a Save file to be used by your batch Script, or are you attempting to use a batch file to edit the Inventory file of another program? If you are just aiming to make a batch game with inventory save, This [Documented Template](https://pastebin.com/yqRSuvPL) should provide plenty of examples on how this can be approached.

Comment: it is save file, that will be used in my batch game. i just need to find way how to write&replace data in these brackets, like i described in post

Comment: In [pure] batch, You cannot re-write partial lines in a file, you need to re-write the whole file, modifying the string value of the desired line. You can redirect output to a file using >"filename.ext" or Append output using >>"filename.ext". You can however use prefixed variables to output all variables that need Saving / Updating Simulataneously. I strongly recommend you test and experiment with the Documented Template for Batch Inventory management that I lnked.

Comment: uh... i strongly need to do this in json, way i ve expalined. maybe i can use another langugae to operate on this, and call it from main batch file?

Comment: You've stated it's a save file for a batch game, so what advantage does JSON offer? The datastructure that you have exampled is not conducive to reading, modifying and rewritng the values. Is it a matter of [Sunk Cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost) or is there a practical reason your adamant that you wish to stick with json and your exampled datastructure?

Comment: thats fanny cause i managed to do it rn, in just 4 lines of code. so i do not know why u are telling me that it is impossible in pure batch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229604/discussion-between-t3rr0r-and-skrampy).

Answer (score 0):

Proposal: Utilise a data structure and storage method suited for batch scripting.

The set command outputs all variables that contain are prefixed with the Arg to Set.
So by Defining All variables that need to be saved with a prefix of '#' and using:
`Set "#" >"output.txt"`

All prefixed variables get output Simultaneously.

With DelayedExpansion Enabled, Lists in Batch Can be defined Like So:
`Set "#Listvar=!ListVar! "ItemName""`

Items  can be removed from a list variable by using Substring Modification like So:
`Set "#Listvar=!Listvar: "ItemName="!"`

Lists can be Tiered / Associated and modified conditionally based on the values.

## The Below is an Integrated Inventory System That uses a combination of Datastructures to effect the sort of result you seek.

Inventory Items have The Following Properties:

- ItemName
- ItemType
- ItemSubType
- ItemWeight
- ItemValue
- Optional:ModiferType=Value

Datastructure is Arranged as follows:

- Lists are Marked by the Prefix #Inventory
- Tier 1: #Inventory.Types

  - Contains Each Unique Category; Tested using Findstr over Save File before Appending Category to Inventory.Types list
- Tier 2: #Inventory.CategoryType

  - Contains Each Unique SubCategory; Tested using Findstr over Save File before Appending SubCategory to Category list
- Tier 3: #Inventory.CategoryType.CategorySubType

  - Contains Each Unique ItemName; Tested using Findstr over Save File before Appending ItemName to SubCategory list

Each Unique Item uses an Array to Store The Items Properties [weight;modifier;salevalue]

- #ItemName.Grams
- #ItemName.Def
- #ItemName.Dmg
- #ItemName.Value

Items that are Equipped are assigned to the #Equipped Array:

- #Equipped.ItemType.ItemSubType=ItemName

When an item is sold or dropped, The output of Set "#" Command is output to findstr to seek out and undefine any variables containing the ItemName, Excluding all #Inventory prefixed variables, allowing all Array values for a given Itemname to be removed.
#Inventory prefixed variables have substring modification used on them to remove the ItmName from the CategorySubtype List. If the CategorySubtype List becomes Empty, It is removed from the CategoryType List. If the CategoryType List becomes Empty, It is removed from the #Inventory.Type List.

The `:Save` function is used to Update the Definitions in the save file to match current definitions, and Calculates #Weight value using the #ItemName.Grams Array, and #Dmg and #Def values using the #Equipped Array

```
::: AUTHOR: T3RRY Created: 06/03/2021 Version: 1.3 Filename: RPGInventorySystem
:# Purpose:  Provide an easy to use, ready to go Template for creating Batch RPG Games
:# Features:
:# - :Login Function that flags if character name is New or Returning
:# - :Getin Input function to restrict and validate player Input
:# - Example Template of Creating Classes with Starting Inventory { :Knight function }
:# - Multipurpose :Inventory Funtion That Saves Inventory changes Immediately
:# - :ManageInventory Function to allow players to well... manage their inventory.
:# - Menu Macro for easy menus.

@Echo off & Goto Prep
=======================================================================:# FUNCTIONS
:# Inventory Arguments and Usage Info:
:# Arg order Mandatory
======================:# ADDING ITEMS TO INVENTORY: Initial Inventory; Loot; Gifts / Rewards; Purchases
:Inventory              <ItemName> <ItemType> <ItemSubType> <ItemWeight> <ItemCost> {Optional:"ModifierType=Value"} {Optional:/F}
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:# Optional Arg "/F": Must be last Arg; Flags the Item as free; Does not Subtract ItemCost from Players #Money
:#  Allows Items to be Looted / Gifted / Rewarded that have value stored for use when Selling Items. See Below
======================:# REMOVING / SELLING ITEMS:
:# Remove item:         <ItemName> /R <ItemSubType>
:#  Optional third Arg is used when selling an Item. May be a Sum, Integer Value or use Array: !#ItemName.Value!
:#  /R - Undefines all array elements containing ItemName in varname or value. Use unique and descriptive Item names.
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:# Sell item:           <ItemName> /R <ItemSubType> <ItemSaleValue>
======================:# EQUIPPING ITEMS:
:# Equip an item   :    <Itemname> /E <ItemSubtype>
======================:# CHECKPOINTS:
:# Save a Checkpoint:   <LabelName> /L
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES - The above Parameter names; #%1.Grams #%1.Value #Display.Weight #%3{i} #Weight List? Count
:#  - Arrays:         #%ItemName%.Grams #%ItemName%.Value #Equipped.%ItemSubType%
:#  - Lists:          #Inventory.Types #Inventory.%ItemType% #Inventory.%ItemType%.%ItemSubType%
:# RECOMMENDATION: Use a selection of Category names for ItemTypes that will be Equipped.
:# - Only one of Each ItemSubType may be Equipped at A time.
:#  - It is appropriate that only 1 pair of Boots may be worn, but multiple pieces of different Armor may be equipped:
:#  - Instead of just Defining all armors to the ItemType Armor:
:#  - Define Type Armor and Subtypes: Helm Mantle Gloves Vambraces Pauldrons Boots Pants
:# DEPENDENCIES - Defined in ':Login': #Name Game.Save
 If /I "%~2" == "/L" (
  Set "#Location=%~1"
  Goto :Save
 )
:# Removes or Sell ItemName From Inventory;  Removes ItemName From ItemSubtype List
 If /I "%~2" == "/R" (
  Set "Value="
  If not "%~5" == "" Set "Value=%~5"
  For /F "Tokens=1,2* Delims==" %%G in (' Set "#" 2^> nul ^|%__Appdir__%findstr.exe /LIC:"%~1" ')Do (
rem /* Test if Variable is a List Variable; If Not Undefines Variable */
   Set "List?=%%G"
   If not "!List?:~0,10!" == "#Inventory" (
    Set "%%G="
   )Else (
rem /* If Variable is a List Variable; Remove ItemName from ItemSubType List */
    Set "%%G=!%%G: "%~1"=!"
Rem /* If ItemSubType List is Empty; Remove ItemSubtype from ItemType List */
    If "!%%G!" == "" (Set "#Inventory.%~3=!#Inventory.%~3: "%~4"=!")
   )
  )
rem /* If Item SaleValue provided; Increment #Money by Value */
  Set /A "#Money+=!Value!+0"
  Goto :Save
 )
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::# Call is Addition to Inventory
:# Build Itemtype Arrays and List Using Parameters
 Set "ItemName=%~1"
 Set "ItemType=%~2"
 Set "ItemSubtype=%~3"
 Set "Count=0"
:# Limit ItemTypes to 36 max supported by Menu macro
 If Not "!#Inventory.%ItemType%!" == "" (
  For %%G in (!#Inventory.%ItemType%!)Do Set /A "Count+=1"
  If !Count! GTR 36 (
   Echo(You own too many types of %ItemType%. !ItemName! cannot be Acquired.
   Exit /B 3
  )
 )
 Set "Count=0"
:# Limit Subtypes to 36 max supported by Menu macro
 If Not "!#Inventory.%ItemType%.%ItemSubType%!" == "" (
  For %%G in (!#Inventory.%ItemType%.%ItemSubType%!)Do Set /A "Count+=1"
  If !Count! GTR 36 (
   Echo(You own too many types of %ItemSubtype%. !ItemName! cannot be Acquired.
   Exit /B 3
  )
 )
 If "%~4" == "" (Set "ItemWeight=0")Else (
  Set "ItemWeight=%~4"
  For /F %%G in ('Set /A #MaxWeight-%~4-#weight')Do if %%G LSS 0 (
   Echo/You are carrying too much.
   Exit /B 2
 ))
:# Determine Value of Item and If item is To be Free or Paid For
 Set "Free.Item="
 Echo(%*|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"/F" > Nul && Set "Free.Item=Y"
 If "%~5"=="" (Set "ItemCost=0")Else (
  Set "ItemCost=%~5"
  If Not Defined Free.Item (
   For /F %%G in ('Set /A #money-%~5')Do if %%G LSS 0 (
    Echo(You cannot afford %ItemName%
    Exit /B 1
   )
  )
 )
:# Define a Modifier To ItemName.modname For Items With Stat Modifiers If supplied
 If not "%~6" == "" If /I not "%~6" == "/F" (
  Set "#%ItemName%.%~6" 2> Nul || (
   Echo(Invalid Argument "[%~6]" In %*
   Echo(Required: "ModifierType=Value"
   Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak
   Pause
   Endlocal & Goto :Eof
  )
 )
:# Define #ItemName Arrays for Grams and Value
 Set "#%ItemName%.Grams=%Itemweight%"
 Set "#%ItemName%.Value=%ItemCost%"
 Echo(!ItemName! added to Inventory.
:# Search savefile for Itemtype; Itemsubtype; and Itemname; Append to relevant list if not present
 %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"!ItemType!" "%Game.Save%" > nul 2> nul || Set "#Inventory.Types=!#Inventory.Types! "!ItemType!""
 %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"!ItemSubType!" "%Game.Save%" > nul 2> nul || Set "#Inventory.%ItemType%=!#Inventory.%ItemType%! "!ItemSubType!""
 %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"!ItemName!" "%Game.Save%" > nul 2> nul || Set "#Inventory.%ItemType%.%ItemSubType%=!#Inventory.%ItemType%.%ItemSubType%! "!ItemName!""
==========
:Save
:# Remove Item Categories from #Inventory.Types list when all Category sub items are sold / dropped.
 For %%G in (!#Inventory.Types!)Do If "!#Inventory.%%~G!" == "" Set "#Inventory.Types=!#Inventory.Types: "%%~G"=!"
 Set /A "#Def=#Dmg=#weight=0"
:# Updates the below Modifiers of all equipped inventory items by summing all ItemName.%%M definitions
 For %%M in (DEF DMG)Do For /F "Tokens=1,2* Delims==" %%G in ('Set "#Equipped"')Do (
  For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%i in ('Set "#%%H"^|%__APPDIR__%Findstr.exe /LIC:".%%M"')Do (
   Set /A "#%%M+=%%i+0"
  )
 )
:# Updates the current weight of all inventory items by summing all ItemName.Grams definitions
 For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%G in (' Set "#" ^| Findstr /LIC:".Grams"')Do Set /A #weight+=%%G
 Set "#Display.weight=%#weight:~0,-3%.%#weight:~-3%"
:# Enact Save for # prefixed variables
:# Saves Game Variables prefixed by # to Game.Save cmd file to be called on Login
 (For /F "tokens=1,2* Delims==" %%G in ('Set "#"')Do Echo(Set "%%G=%%H") >"%Game.Save%"
 Exit /B 0
=================================================
:ManageInventory {Optional:/E /S /D}
:# Control Available Inventory options by Calling ManageInventory with the Options you wish
:# to allow according to the current Gamestate.
 Set "MI.Options="
 If not "%~1" == "" Echo/%*|Findstr /LIC:"E" > Nul && Set "MI.Options=!MI.Options! Equip"
 If not "%~1" == "" Echo/%*|Findstr /LIC:"S" > Nul && Set "MI.Options=!MI.Options! Sell"
 If not "%~1" == "" Echo/%*|Findstr /LIC:"D" > Nul && Set "MI.Options=!MI.Options! Drop"
:# /R - Removes the Sell option from Invetory Action
:# RESERVED VARIABLES - Type; SubType; Action; All Menu Macro Reserved Variables
:# DEPENDENCIES -Functions: Inventory; Save -Macro: Menu -Variables: #Money #Equipped
:#                          Inventory Function Defines Lists used with Each Submenu.
:# This function returns no Errorlevels.
CLS
 Echo(Credit: !#Money! Damage: !#Dmg! Defence: !#Def! Burden: !#Display.Weight! kg /!#MaxWeight:~0,-3!.!#MaxWeight:~-3! kg.
 Set #Equipped 2> nul
:# Choose Action Type or Exit ManageInventory Function; Each Submenu can abort to this Primary Menu
 %Menu% Exit !MI.Options!
 CLS
 Set "Action=!Option!"
 Echo(Select Inventory Category:
 %Menu% Return !#Inventory.Types!
 If "!Option!" == "Return" (Goto :ManageInventory)Else CLS
 Set "Type=!Option!"
 Echo(Select a type of !Type! to !Action!:
 %Menu% Return !#Inventory.%Type%!
 If "!Option!" == "Return" (Goto :ManageInventory)Else CLS
 Set "SubType=%Option%"
:# Apply action type to selected ItemName
:# If Equipping; Handle Two Handed / [One Handed/Off Hand] Equipment Conflict
 Echo(Selecting a !Subtype! from your !Type! Will !Action! it. Return [0] To cancel.
 %Menu% Return !#Inventory.%Type%.%SubType%!
 If Not "!Option!" == "Return" (
  If "!Action!" == "Equip" (
   Set "#Equipped.%Type%.%Subtype%=%Option%"
   If /I "%SubType%" == "Two Handed" (Set "#Equipped.Weapons.One Handed="&Set "#Equipped.Weapons.Off Hand=")
   If /I "%SubType%" == "One Handed" (Set "#Equipped.Weapons.Two Handed=")
   If /I "%SubType%" == "Off Hand" (Set "#Equipped.Weapons.Two Handed=")
   Call :Save
  )
  If "!Action!" == "Sell" (
   Echo(Sell Value: $!#%Option%.Value!. Confirm [Y/N]
   For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C:YN')Do If %%O==Y Call :Inventory "%Option%" /R "!Type!" "!SubType!" "!#%Option%.Value!"
  )
  If "!Action!" == "Drop" Call :Inventory "%Option%" /R "!Type!" "!SubType!"
 )
Goto :ManageInventory
=================================================
:login
:# clear any preexisting definitions
 (For /F "tokens=1,2* Delims==" %%G in ('Set "#"')Do Set "%%G=") 2> nul
:# Login Errorlevels: [2:User quit during Login.] [1:New Character] [0:Existing Character]
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES:
:# - #Name #Pass Verify
:#   #Name used to create a .cmd file that is called when the user logs back in to the character to reassign
:#   # prefixed variables.
CLS
 Echo(Existing Characters:
 (Dir /B "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_Save.cmd" > Nul 2> nul || Echo(None. )
 For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=_" %%G in (' Dir /B "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_Save.cmd" 2^> nul ')Do Echo(%%G
rem /* example definitions */
 Call :GetIn #Name "[a-zA-Z ]*" /C /S /P:Enter your characters name
 If Not "%Errorlevel%" == "0" Goto :login
 Call :GetIn #Pass "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" /S /P:Enter your four Digit Pin
 If Not "%Errorlevel%" == "0" Goto :login
 Set "Verify=%#Pass%"
 Set "Game.Save=%TEMP%\%~n0_%#Name%_Save.cmd"
rem /* load saved values */
 If Exist "%Game.Save%" Call "%Game.Save%"
 If /I not "%Verify%" == "%#Pass%" (
  Echo(Invalid Password
  %Menu% Exit Retry
rem /* Flag quit program */
  Goto :Login
 )
rem /* offer delete/ login if exists */
 If Exist "%Game.Save%" (
rem /* Flag Existing Character Errorlevel 0 */
  %Menu% "Remove Character" "Continue"
  If /I "!Option!"=="Continue" Exit /b 0
  %Menu% "Abort" "Proceed"
  If /I "!Option!"=="Abort" Goto :Login
  Del "%Game.Save%"
  Goto :Login
 ) Else (
rem /* Flag New Character Errorlevel 1 */
  Exit /B 1
 )
=====================================================
:GetIn [ReturnVar] ["qouted findstr search pattern"]  [Optional:"/C" - required for patterns with spaces] [Optional "/S" - Suppress input accepted] [/P:Custom Prompt]
:# Input validation function for restricting input to desired character classes or [limited] Regex Patterns.
:# -IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES: InputParams /C /P /S rVar Pattern Exit.Code
:# - GetIn Errorlevels: 
:#  - Errorlevel 3 - User has failed to provide valid input * OR * regex pattern is
:#    invalid * OR * GetIn is a called label in a file that has recieved input
:#    from a pipe that has not been handeled before the call.
:#  - Errorlevel 2 - GetIn is a script that has been invoked by a pipe
:#  - Errorlevel 1 - GetIn has been called without Arg 2 for Regex Pattern
:#  - Errorlevel 0 - Input has been assigned that matches the Regex Pattern
:# GetIn Usage Examples - Description is replaced with Arg 1-ReturnVar:
:#  Call :GetIn Pin "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" /S /P:Enter a four Digit Pin Number
:#  Call :GetIn Alphanumeric-String "[0-9a-zA-Z]*"
:#  Call :GetIn semicolon-delimited-hexadecimal-String "[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][:][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]"
:#  Call :GetIn AlphaString-with-3-Digit-Numeric-suffix "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
:#  Call :GetIn list-of-delimited-words "[a-zA-Z, ]*" /C
:#  Call :GetIn pair-of-delimited-numbers "[0-9]*[, ][0-9]*" /C

 SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "/C=" & Set "/P=" & Set "/S="
 Set InputParams=%*
 If Not "!InputParams:/C=!" == "!InputParams!" Set "/C=_"
 If Not "!InputParams:/S=!" == "!InputParams!" Set "/S=_"
 If Not "!InputParams:/P=!" == "!InputParams!" (
  Set "/P=!InputParams:*/P:=!"
  Set "/P=!/P:"=!"
 )
rem [ test if standalone script - if so test if accessed by pipe; reject execution if true ]
 If "%~0" == "%~n0" For %%G in (!cmdcmdline!)Do Echo/%%~G|Findstr.exe /LIC:"/S" > nul 2> nul && (Set "Exit.Code=2" & Goto :Getin.Err)
:GetInRetry
 Del /Q "%TEMP%\%~n0_validate.~tmp" 2> nul
 If !Exit.Code! GTR 5 Goto :Getin.Err
 Set "rVar="
 If "%~2" == "" GOTO :Getin.Err
 Setlocal DISABLEdelayedExpansion & rem ::: display occurances of carets [^] in pattern
 Endlocal & Set "Pattern=%~2"
 If Not Defined /P (
  Set /P "rVar=Input Format for %1:!LF!!Pattern!!LF!!LF!Enter %1: "
 )Else  Set /P "rVar=!/P!: "
 If "!rVar!" == "" (Set /A "Exit.Code+=1" & <nul Set /P"= ^! Invalid value.!LF!" & Goto :GetInRetry)
 > "%TEMP%\%~n0_validate.~tmp" (Echo/!rVar!)
 If Defined /C (
  Type "%TEMP%\%~n0_validate.~tmp" | %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RXC:"%~2" >nul || (Set /A "Exit.Code+=1" & <nul Set /P"= ^! Invalid value. !LF!" & Goto :GetInRetry)
 ) Else (
  Type "%TEMP%\%~n0_validate.~tmp" | %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RX "^%~2$" >nul || (Set /A "Exit.Code+=1" & <nul Set /P"=- ^! Invalid value. !LF!" & Goto :GetInRetry)
 )
 If not defined /S Echo/%1: [!rVar!] Accepted
 ENDLOCAL & Set "%~1=%rVar%"
 Del /Q "%TEMP%\%~n0_validate.~tmp"
 Exit /B 0
:GetIn.Err
Exit /B %Exit.Code%
===========================:# DEFINE INITIAL INVENTORY - EXAMPLE Only
:Knight Starter Pack
:# Example of defining initial variables for a new character prior to commencing gameplay
:# IMPORTANT - Inventory function is Dependant on #Money #MaxWeight and #Weight variables.
 Set /A "#Money=500,#MaxWeight=25000,#Weight=0"
:# suppress output of Inventory added notifcation by redirecting to nul as desired.
 Call :Inventory "Dagger" Weapons "Off Hand" 250 50 "DMG=5" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Buckler" Weapons "Off Hand" 400 40 "DEF=6" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Short sword" Weapons "One Handed" 4000 250 "DMG=10" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Twin Bladed Katana" Weapons "Two Handed" 5500 350 "DMG=12" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Leather Cap" Armor Helm 500 25 "DEF=3" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Faded Map" Miscellaneous Maps 20 "DEF=5" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Healing Potion" Potions Restorative 10 25 "Heal=30" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Old Key" Miscellaneous Keys 10 1 /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Worn Leather Vambraces" Armor Vambraces 1000 15 "DEF=2" /F > nul
 Call :Inventory "Boots of Luck" Armor Boots 1500 50 "DEF=4" /F > nul
Goto :Eof
===========================:# END OF FUNCTIONS
:Prep
=====================================================:# MACRO DEFINITIONS
===================================:# MENU macro prep and Definition :::
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES:
:# - LF \N Game.Save
(Set LF=^

%= Linefeed var used for multi-line output in GetIn macro - Do not modify. =%)
(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify. =%)

:# Enable environment for macro expansion, Arrays and code block variable operations
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
==================================================================
:# Menu macro escaped for Definition with DelayedExpansion Enabled
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES: Menu CH# CHCS Options Option Opt[i] Option.Output Cholist DIV
:# Key index list Allows 36 menu options. Component of Menu Macro
 Set "ChoList=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
rem /* Get console width for dividing line. */
 for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"Columns"`) do Set /A "Console_Width=%%W"
:# Build dividing line for menu output.
 Set "DIV="&For /L %%i in (2 1 %Console_Width%)Do Set "DIV=!DIV!-"
:# Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
==== Set Menu=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^!DIV^^!%\n%
%= Reset CH# index value for Opt[#]     =%  Set "CH#=0"%\n%
%= Undefine choice option key list      =%  Set "CHCS="%\n%
%= For Each in list;                    =%  For %%G in (^^!Options^^!)Do (%\n%
%= For Option Index value               =%   For %%i in (^^!CH#^^!)Do (%\n%
%= Build the Choice key list and Opt[#] =%    Set "CHCS=^!CHCS^!^!ChoList:~%%i,1^!"%\n%
%= array using the character at the     =%    Set "Opt[^!ChoList:~%%i,1^!]=%%~G"%\n%
%= current substring index.             =%    Set "option.output=%%~G"%\n%
%= Display ; removing # variable prefix =%    Echo([^^!ChoList:~%%i,1^^!] ^^!Option.output:#=^^!%\n%
%= Increment Opt[#] Index var 'CH#'     =%    Set /A "CH#+=1"%\n%
%= Close CH# loop                       =%   )%\n%
%= Close Options loop                   =%  )%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^!DIV^^!%\n%
%= Select option by character index     =%  For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('Choice /N /C:^^!CHCS^^!')Do (%\n%
%= Assign return var 'OPTION' with the  =%   Set "Option=^!Opt[%%o]^!"%\n%
%= value selected from Opt[CH#] array.  =%   If /I "^!Option^!" == "Exit" Exit /B 2%\n%
%= Return to previous script on Exit    =%  )%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List   =% )Else Set Options=
========================================== ::: End Menu Definition
:StartGame
:# Make the Session Local
 Setlocal
==========================================:# MAIN GAME SCRIPT [ EXAMPLE ]
:# To Create / Continue a Character; Call Login. Errorlevel 0 = Returning Character
:# Modify The reponse to Errorlevel 1 [New Character] As you Wish to facilitate Creation of Character Classes.
:# Suggested: Use the Menu Macro with a list of Character Classes corresponding to functions and Call the selected class Label (IE - Call :Rogue)
 Call :Login
 If Errorlevel 2 Goto :Eof
 If Errorlevel 1 (
  Echo(Select your Class:
  %Menu% Exit "Knight" "Rogue"
  Call :!Option! 2>nul || (
   Echo(The !Option! Class has not been created yet. Use the example of the :Knight function to create your own Classes.
   Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak > Nul
   Pause
   Endlocal
   Goto :StartGame
  )
 )
:# Use Labels as checkpoints by Defining them to the Variable #Location
 If Errorlevel 0 If Defined #Location (Goto :!#Location!)
:# To [S]ell [E]quip or [D]rop Inventory:
:# If the Player is not in a Town / Shop; Use: Call :ManageInventory /ED to Lock out Sale of Items
 Call :ManageInventory /ESD
:Home This and below Label locations are examples of using Label Checkpoints
 CLS
 Call :Inventory Home /L
:# Use last selected option to prevent recursive calls.
 If not "!Option!" == "Home" (
  %Menu% Exit "Manage Inventory" "Travel"
 )Else %Menu% Exit "Manage Inventory"
 If "!Option!" == "Manage Inventory" (
  Call :!Option: =! /ESD
  Goto :Home
 )
 If not "!Option!" == "Travel" Goto :Eof
:Travel
 CLS
 Call :Inventory Travel /L
 Echo(Choose a Direction:
 %Menu% Exit Home East West North South
 Call :!Option: =! 2> Nul || If not Errorlevel 2 (
  Echo That Direction has not been Scripted yet. You'll have to make your own Adventure.
  Pause
 )
 Goto :Travel
```

Example Output:

- Menu Dividing line removed from output to meet Answer Character count limit. *

```
Existing Characters:
me
Enter your characters name: NewB
Enter your four Digit Pin: 1234
Select your Class:
[0] Exit
[1] Knight
[2] Rogue
```

```
Credit: 500 Damage: 0 Defence: 0 Burden: 13.190 kg /25.000 kg.
[0] Exit
[1] Equip
[2] Sell
[3] Drop
```

```
Select Inventory Category:
[0] Return
[1] Weapons
[2] Armor
[3] Miscellaneous
[4] Potions

Select a type of Weapons to Equip:
[0] Return
[1] Off Hand
[2] One Handed
[3] Two Handed

Select a type of Weapons to Equip:
[0] Return
[1] Off Hand
[2] One Handed
[3] Two Handed

Selecting a One Handed from your Weapons Will Equip it. Return [0] To cancel.
[0] Return
[1] Short sword

Credit: 500 Damage: 10 Defence: 0 Burden: 13.190 kg /25.000 kg.
#Equipped.Weapons.One Handed=Short sword
[0] Exit
[1] Equip
[2] Sell
[3] Drop

Select Inventory Category:
[0] Return
[1] Weapons
[2] Armor
[3] Miscellaneous
[4] Potions

Select a type of Weapons to Sell:
[0] Return
[1] Off Hand
[2] One Handed
[3] Two Handed

Selecting a One Handed from your Weapons Will Sell it. Return [0] To cancel.
[0] Return
[1] Short sword
Sell Value: $250. Confirm [Y/N]

Credit: 750 Damage: 0 Defence: 0 Burden: 9.190 kg /25.000 kg.
[0] Exit
[1] Equip
[2] Sell
[3] Drop
```